# HTML form not creating in PHP loop

Tags: php, html

I can't create HTML form in a php loop in a function. Here what I did:

```
    foreach ($products as $product) {

            $html .= "<tr>
                <form method='POST' id='form-".$product->virtuemart_product_id."' class='product js-recalculate' action = '' >";

                $html .="<td>".$product->product_s_desc."</td>";                

                if($showattribute == 1) {
                    $html .="<td class='product_attribute' id='PerUnitAttr".$product->virtuemart_product_id."'>";

                        if (!empty($product->customfieldsCart)) {

                            foreach ($product->customfieldsCart as $field) {

                                $html .= "<p><b>". $field->custom_title."</b></p>";
                                $html .= "<p>". $field->display."</p>";

                            }

                        }
                    $html .= "</td>";
                }
        $html .= 
                '<td><span class="quantity-box">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" id="PerUnitQuantity'.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'" name="quantity[]" value="1"/>
                </span>
                <span class="quantity-controls">
                    <input type="button" id="PerUnitPlus'.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'" class="quantity-controls quantity-plus"  />
                    <input type="button" id="PerUnitMinus'.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'" class="quantity-controls quantity-minus" /> 
                </span>
                <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="'. $product->product_name .'"/> 

                ';


            $html .="<td><span style='margin-left: 8px;' id='PerUnitTotal".$product->virtuemart_product_id."'> 0 </span> ".$currency->getSymbol()."</td>
</form></tr>";
}
return $html;
```

But that form not showing up & inserting closing tag before in where I ended it. It's  something like this:

```
    <tr>

        <form id="form-72" class="product js-recalculate" action="" method="POST">
        </form>
        <td></td>
<tr>

    <form id="form-6" class="product js-recalculate" action="" method="POST"></form>
    <td></td>
```

In where I did mistake ?

For more specific what I wanted to do the output will be like this:

```
<table>
loop start
<form action='' id='id='form-".$data."'>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</form>
loop end
</table>
```

But output not showing correctly.

Comment: you notice that you didn't close off your first echo **-->** `$html .= "<tr>                <form method='POST' id='form-".$product->virtuemart_product_id."' class='product js-recalculate' action = '' >`? You're missing a `";`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed that but it was correct. During asking question I reduced code that time it was mistake. But the form not showing up in html table. Please check

Comment: OK I got it. I can't use form tag inside a table :(

Comment: Are you trying to create a form for each `$product` ?

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
$html .= "<tr>
                <form method='POST' id='form-".$product->virtuemart_product_id."' class='product js-recalculate' action = '' >
```

become:

```
$html .= "<tr>
                <form method='POST' id='form-".$product->virtuemart_product_id."' class='product js-recalculate' action = '' >";
```